# Node js rl repeat last prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js

This seems like something that should be easy to do, but I can't find anything in the docs.

I have a series of questions that I want to ask, and one of them I want to re-ask until I get a valid answer. Like this:

```
rl.question('Author: ', function(answer) { //question #1
    author = answer; //Use that value, move to next question
    rl.question('What Title should be shown in browser tabs for this site? ', function(answer) { //question #2
        title = answer; //Move on...
        rl.question('Include the tippy.js library? ', function(answer) { //question #3
            if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'yes' || answer == 'Yes' || answer == 'Y') {
                console.log("Will include tippy.js");
                //Done with app
            } else if (answer == 'n' || answer == 'no' || answer == 'N' || answer == 'No') {
                console.log("Will not include tippy.js");
                //Done with app
            } else {
                console.log("Invalid response");
                //Re-ask question #3 without asking questions #1 and #2
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Suggestions? Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: You've seem to have a solution right there. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't know what to put where the comment says "Re-ask question #3 without asking questions #1 and #2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just stick it in a function then call that function every time you need to repeat it.

```
function shouldIncludeTippy() {
  rl.question('Include the tippy.js library? ', function(answer) {
    if (answer === 'y' ...) {
      console.log('Will include tippy.js');
    } else if (answer === 'n' ...) {
      console.log('Will not include tippy.js');
    } else {
      console.log('Invalid response');
      shouldIncludeTippy();
    }
  });
}
```

Then your code reads like this:

```
rl.question('Author: ', function(answer) { //question #1
    author = answer; //Use that value, move to next question
    rl.question('What Title should be shown in browser tabs for this site? ', function(answer) { //question #2
        title = answer; //Move on...
        shouldIncludeTippy();
    })
});
```